# Null character is not acting as end of string in assembly (NASM)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, null-terminated

In c language we can use '\0' null character as end of string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char msg[] = "hello\0world";
    printf("msg = %s", msg);
}
```

This code will print just **hello**. Not world.

But In linux x86 NASM I'm using the following code but it is printing **helloworld**.

```
section .data
msg db "hello", 0, "world"

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, 20
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
    ret
```

Why null character is not working here as end of string? And what can I do to get that in assembly?

Comment: You specified a message length argument in `edx`. This is an indication that the null-terminated convention does not apply. You were (un)lucky that the string was not followed by garbage.

Comment: @YvesDaoust write system call doesn't print garbage how big size i put in `edx`.

Comment: That's because there isn't any garbage anywhere in `.data` (because it only has what you put in it), and it's followed by an unmapped page so `write()` stops there.

Comment: Pipe your program into `hexdump -C` to see the zero byte as part of the output.  (And more zeros after since you wrote 20 total bytes).  Or use `strace -s 40 ./a.out` which also decodes system call args, bumping up the string length limit so you can see more of it.

Answer (score 3):

You use the [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call to write the data with the exact size you specify. The `write` function have no knowledge of the data it writes, it's just a series of bytes.

If you want to write a null-terminated string, you either need to find the position of the terminator and calculate the length from that position, or use a function that knows about C null-terminated strings.